# Regex to allow numbers 1 - 28

Tags: regex

Can someone help me write a regex that will allow numbers 1 - 28 only?  Currently I have [1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8]$  and this works fine up to 19 but after that it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: Use http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/, check *Match whole line*.

Comment: [Unrelated...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151065/create-a-regex-to-match-a-given-range-of-integers-in-a-given-radix?rq=1)